# cache.ccf file not picked up by javastravav3api

Tags: playframework, sbt, jcs, strava

location of cache.ccf file

stk

-app
 -bin
 -build.sbt
 -cache.ccf
 -conf
 -lib
 -libexec
 -LICENSE
 -logs
 -project
 -public
 -README
 -target
 -test

**stacktrack:**

```
play.api.http.HttpErrorHandlerExceptions$$anon$1: Execution exception[[CompletionException: org.apache.commons.jcs.access.exception.CacheException: Failed to read configuration file [/cache.ccf]]]
    at play.api.http.HttpErrorHandlerExceptions$.throwableToUsefulException(HttpErrorHandler.scala:280)
    at play.api.http.DefaultHttpErrorHandler.onServerError(HttpErrorHandler.scala:206)
    at play.api.GlobalSettings$class.onError(GlobalSettings.scala:160)
    at play.api.DefaultGlobal$.onError(GlobalSettings.scala:188)
    at play.api.http.GlobalSettingsHttpErrorHandler.onServerError(HttpErrorHandler.scala:98)
    at play.core.server.netty.PlayRequestHandler$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$apply$1.applyOrElse(PlayRequestHandler.scala:100)
    at play.core.server.netty.PlayRequestHandler$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$apply$1.applyOrElse(PlayRequestHandler.scala:99)
    at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$recoverWith$1.apply(Future.scala:344)
    at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$recoverWith$1.apply(Future.scala:343)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:32)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: org.apache.commons.jcs.access.exception.CacheException: Failed to read configuration file [/cache.ccf]
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.encodeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:292)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:308)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniApply(CompletableFuture.java:593)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniApply.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:577)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:474)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeExceptionally(CompletableFuture.java:1977)
    at scala.concurrent.java8.FuturesConvertersImpl$CF.apply(FutureConvertersImpl.scala:21)
    at scala.concurrent.java8.FuturesConvertersImpl$CF.apply(FutureConvertersImpl.scala:18)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:32)
    at scala.concurrent.BatchingExecutor$Batch$$anonfun$run$1.processBatch$1(BatchingExecutor.scala:63)
Caused by: org.apache.commons.jcs.access.exception.CacheException: Failed to read configuration file [/cache.ccf]
    at org.apache.commons.jcs.engine.control.CompositeCacheManager.configure(CompositeCacheManager.java:359)
    at org.apache.commons.jcs.engine.control.CompositeCacheManager.getInstance(CompositeCacheManager.java:190)
    at org.apache.commons.jcs.engine.control.CompositeCacheManager.getInstance(CompositeCacheManager.java:161)
    at org.apache.commons.jcs.JCS.getCacheManager(JCS.java:156)
    at org.apache.commons.jcs.JCS.getGroupCacheInstance(JCS.java:219)
    at javastrava.cache.impl.StravaCacheImpl.<init>(StravaCacheImpl.java:40)
    at javastrava.api.v3.service.impl.ActivityServiceImpl.<init>(ActivityServiceImpl.java:93)
    at javastrava.api.v3.service.impl.ActivityServiceImpl.instance(ActivityServiceImpl.java:58)
    at javastrava.api.v3.auth.model.Token.<init>(Token.java:114)
    at javastrava.api.v3.auth.impl.retrofit.AuthorisationServiceImpl.tokenExchange(AuthorisationServiceImpl.java:40)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

default location for cache.ccf in a play application is conf

conf directory is treated as resource directory.